# Limit points in open sets of the real line

Tags: real-analysis

Is it necessarily true that if I have an open set $E$ such that $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, then there is a limit point of $E$ that lies outside of the set $E$?

I can see that, for example, open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ have limit points outside of $E$, but is there an instance where this is not true?

Furthermore, suppose I take another open set $E \subset X$ where $X$ is an arbitrary space and $E$ is open. Is it true that $E$ does not contain any limit points of its complement?

I had an idea about the second statement. Correct me if I am wrong, but if I choose the discrete metric space, then there are no limit points, and any singleton is open. Thus, any singleton vacuously contains limit points of its complement since there are not any. Is this valid?

Thanks!

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$ it is not possible since it is connected. If a proper open set has all the limit points then it will be closed thus the space will be not connected.

Comment: @Infinity_hunter Thanks so much! That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: In the complete metric space, every point is a limit of any set containing itself, but is not a limit of any set not containing itself. No set contains limit points of its complement. Every set is both open and closed.

Comment: @1Rock so are you saying that my counterexample does not work for the second statement? Sorry, maybe I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, your counterexample doesn't work. In fact, "not containing limit points of its complement" is a requirement for open sets. $x$ is only a limit point of $A$ if every open set $B$ containing $x$ contains a point in $A$, and clearly if $A:=X \backslash E$, then $E$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ which doesn't contain any points in $A$.

Comment: @1Rock To make sure I am understanding, you are arguing by contradiction, right? You are saying that, suppose $x$ is a limit point of $E^{C}$, then suppose $x \in E$ for a contradiction. Then, as $E$ is open, there exists some neighborhood around $x$ which does not contain points in $E^{C}$, so contradiction.

Comment: You can think of it that way - it's logically equivalent to what I was saying. I was just saying, suppose $x \in E$, then $x$ is not a limit point of $E^C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take $E:=\emptyset$, then $E$ has no limit points outside $E$.

More generally, if $X$ is any topological space, $E\subset T$ has a limit point which is not in $E$, if and only if $E$ has a *boundary point* (i.e. a point which is a limit point both of points in $E$ and of points not in $E$). A topological space is *connected* if and only if it isn't the union of two disjoint non-empty open sets - you can take this as the definition of "connected". A discrete metric space is sometimes called a *totally disconnected space*, because every set is both open and closed.